# DOJO - Hide Menu items for DropDownMenu

Tags: javascript, dojo

The menu items getting scattered while loading for the first time.
Looking for a way to hide the component until it loads completely and fits on page.

```
<script>
    require([ "dijit/DropDownMenu", "dijit/MenuSeparator",
            "dijit/PopupMenuItem", "dijit/MenuItem", 
            "dijit/TooltipDialog" ]);
</script>

<div data-dojo-type="dijit.DropDownMenu" id="navMenu" >

<div data-dojo-type="dijit.MenuItem" class="item dijitMenuItemSelected">Home</div>

<div data-dojo-type="dijit.PopupMenuItem" class="item">
    <span>Services</span>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.DropDownMenu" id="submenu2">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit.MenuItem" data-dojo-props="onClick:function(){}">Consulting</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-dojo-type="dijit.MenuItem" class="item">Why us?</div>

<div data-dojo-type="dijit.MenuItem" class="item">FAQs</div>

<div data-dojo-type="dijit.MenuItem" class="item">Contact us</div>
```

Comment: You could always add style="display:none" to your navMenu and then at the end of the page change it to "display:block" or "display:inline" depending on how you want it to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your `<script>` I have change to this. And add function to change style, that will do on load complete.

```
<script>
    require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-style", "dijit/DropDownMenu", "dijit/MenuSeparator", "dijit/PopupMenuItem", "dijit/MenuItem", "dijit/TooltipDialog", "dojo/domReady!"],

    function (dom, domStyle) {
        var controlDisplay = dom.byId("controlDisplay");
        domStyle.set(controlDisplay, "display", "block");
    });
</script>
```

In the body, I have adding the `<div>` that hide all of the item.

```
<div id="controlDisplay" style="display:none;">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.DropDownMenu" id="navMenu">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit.MenuItem" class="item dijitMenuItemSelected">Home</div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit.PopupMenuItem" class="item">
            <span>Services</span>
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit.DropDownMenu" id="submenu2">
                <div data-dojo-type="dijit.MenuItem" data-dojo-props="onClick:function(){}">Consulting</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit.MenuItem" class="item">Why us?</div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit.MenuItem" class="item">FAQs</div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit.MenuItem" class="item">Contact us</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

***First, it's will not appear until load complete. The JS will change style of `<div>` to display all.***

See in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eqN4m/)

Answer (score 0):

It worked after I added the below script with display:none style.

```
require(["dojo/ready", "dojo/parser", "dijit/registry", "dijit/Dialog"], function(ready, parser, registry){
ready(function(){
    require(["dojo/_base/fx", "dojo/on", "dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!"], function(fx, on, dom) {
        fx.fadeOut({duration: 250, node: dom.byId("loader"), onEnd: function() { loader.style.display = "none";  } }).play(250);
    });
}); });
```